Expo gitignore ios and android folders
My generated info.plist has some identifiers such Google Login client ID. While this isn't a "secret", I don't want to commit this to a public git repo.
Given the entire ios and android folders are generated when I run "npx expo prebuild --clean", why not add these folders to gitignore? Alternatively, can I add the info.plist to gitignore safely?
